# How to combine a List values into a String

Tags: scala

I have a case class like this:

```
case class MyClass(name: String, values: Seq[String])
```

If I make a string list like this:

```
scala> l
res19: List[MyClass] = List(MyClass(firstvar,List(one,two,three)), MyClass(secondvar,List(23423, 234234)))
```

How can I turn the above into a string like this:

```
"firstvar_one-two-three_secondvar_23423-234234"
```

Comment: What have you tried? - Take a look to [`map`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#map[B](f:A=%3EB):List[B]) and to [`mkString`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#mkString(sep:String):String)

Answer (score 2):

A combination of `map` and `mkString` should do the trick:

```
l.map(mc => mc.name + "_" + mc.values.mkString("-")).mkString("_")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can accumulator pattern which is `foldLeft`,

```
final case class MyClass(name: String, values: Seq[String])

val data = List(MyClass("firstvar", List("one", "two", "three")),
                MyClass("secondvar", List("23423", "234234")))

val res = data.zipWithIndex.foldLeft("") {
  case (acc, (elem, 0)) => 
    acc + elem.name + "_" + elem.values.mkString("-")
  case (acc, (elem, _)) =>
    acc + "_" + elem.name + "_" + elem.values.mkString("-")
}
```

// output - https://scastie.scala-lang.org/prayagupd/M48HqDp9SMqbCy1Q083Q8g/4

```
firstvar_one-two-three_secondvar_23423-234234
```

Or just use `.map` with `.mkString`.

```
scala> data.map { elem => elem.name + "_" + elem.values.mkString("-") }.mkString("_")
res5: String = firstvar_one-two-three_secondvar_23423-234234
```